# Attempt to read form field value throwns keyerror when used with jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, datepicker

I am new to Django framework and am running into the following issue.  Any help to resolve the issue will be much appreciated.

Background:

I am using the jQuery datePicker to gather date input. I am able to see the calendar show up on the (Appointment) form and select a date from the calendar. However, once submitted, attempt to extract the selected date, in the post processing function, throws a keyerror.

I don't know if this has anything to do with the fact that I didn't manually enter "perfDate", but rather made a selection on the calendar.
The Django debugs show that the POST data as shown here-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TTov.jpg)

Following are my form, template and views files:

forms.py:

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

class AppointmentForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        widgets = {
            'perfDate': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
        }
```

datePicker.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
... JS code...
</head>
    <body>
        <form action="/users/makeReservation/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <!--{{ form.date }} -->
            <p>Desired date:<p>
        <input name="perfDate" type="text" id="id_date"></p>
            <!-- The rest of my form -->
            <input type="submit" value="Reserve" />
        </form>
    </body>
```

views.py:

```
def makeReservation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        aptForm = AppointmentForm(request.POST)
        # Have we been provided with a valid form?
        if aptForm.is_valid():
            aptDate = aptForm.cleaned_data['perfDate'])
            ...
        else:
            # The supplied form contained errors - just print them to the terminal.
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        aptForm = AppointmentForm(request.POST)
        return render(request, 'datePicker.html', {'form' : aptForm})
```

Thanks,
/Baktha Muralidharan